# Craft 3 attachment email

Tags: craft3, emails, modules

I need to add an "attachment" to an email sent by Craft CMS 3.

I used a custom "Module" for this with a "Model", "Service", "Record" and "Controller"

I did some research but did not find any clear answers on how to do it.

**How to send a email with an attachment?**

---- Update -----

Here's what I need to do

Example :

Person A 
Fill the form with file a file ( like doc, pdf etc... )

Prepare the email with the custom "module"

**Do I have to upload the file somehow on the server before do the attachement in the email ?**

Send the email with the file in attachement to Person B

Answer (score 2):

Assuming what you're trying to attach is on the local filesystem, you can see an example of this here: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/craftnet/blob/master/src/orders/OrderBehavior.php#L160-L182

Essentially, you'd just use [attachContent](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/doc/api/2.2/yii-swiftmailer-message#attachContent()-detail), but there is also an [attach](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/doc/api/2.2/yii-swiftmailer-message#attach()-detail) method:

```
->attachContent($pdf, [
    'fileName' => $filename,
    'contentType' => 'application/pdf',
])
```

Comment: Here's what I need to do

Example :

Person A 
Fill the form with a file ( like doc, pdf etc... )

Prepare the email with the custom "module"

Do I have to upload the file somehow on the server before do the attachement in the email ?

Send the email with the file in attachement to Person B

Comment: Yes, the file would need to be uploaded to the server somewhere so you could use it as an attachment in your email.